# test all combinations of parameters excluding one specific combination

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, tdd

I want to create tests that tests all combinations of parameters excluding one combination that will have a different expected result.

So far I have come up with

```
[TestCase(false, false, ExpectedResult = false)]
[TestCase(false, true, ExpectedResult = false)]
[TestCase(true, false, ExpectedResult = false)]
[TestCase(true, true, ExpectedResult = true)]
public bool Test(bool paramA bool paramB)
{
    var target = new MyComand(paramA, paramB);
    return target.CanExecute();
}

// this class is made up, but shows the basic concept
public class MyCommand
{
    bool _preConditionA;
    bool _preConditionB;

    public MyCommand(bool preConditionA, bool preConditionB)
    {
            _preConditionA = preConditionA;
            _preConditionB = preConditionB;
    }

    public bool CanExecute()
    {
        if (_preConditionA == false)
            return false;

        if (_preConditionB == false)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Or with some crazy `[TestCaseSource]`.
Both cases have a problem with the readability for me personally.
This gets more complicated when the parameters are not only boolean.
I checked into the `[Values]` and `[Combinatorical]` attributes, but they don't really work for my case.

Does anybody know any other way to solve this?

Comment: Could you give an example of data that "work for your case" to make this question less abstract?

Comment: Why doesn't `Combinatorial` work for your test? It looks like a perfect use case.

Comment: @GabrielNegut [Combinatorical] will test all combinations, including the one that is the exception of I understand correctly. Problem there is I would have to write a load of code to find out if the current test is testing that special test case

Comment: @rudolf_franek the code explains it. I want all combinations but one of 2 Boolean to pass a test. I solved it using test cases and a return value

Comment: @HankTheTank Could you then rephrase the question? To make it clear which part of the text is statement and which part is question?

Comment: @rudolf_franek I extended the code to show the production code I want to test.
I am looking for a more elegant way to test these preconditions. With 2 boolean parameters it is still ok, but we have pre-conditions with up to 6 pre conditions.
To test them means I need to test 64 [TestCase] attributes to test they apply. And basically I only want one testcase to return true!
This is why I am not happy with the parameterized tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anybody know any other way to solve this?

One possible solution is to use [Assumptions](http://nunit.org/docs/2.5.4/theory.html) to skip the combinations where the arguments are not expected to produce the post condition being checked by the test.

Comment: How would you implement the example with Assumptions?